# If $a > b > 0$ and $c=a+b$, then $c \bmod a = b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have met the following theorem from the book *Introduction to Algorithms* (3rd ed.) in the number theory section. The theorem states that

> Prove that if $a>b>0$ and $c=a+b$, then $c \bmod a=b$.

Please help. In my mind, the main aspect is that because $a>b>0$, it means $c$ is also more then $0$ and each $a$ and $b$, and also $c/a=1$, so remainder is equal automatically to $b$, or $c=1 \cdot a+b$ (because $a>b$). Please tell me if I am correct.

Comment: Your argument seems valid to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The division theorem for integers tells us that given $n, d > 0$, there exists *unique* pair $(q,r)$ (both integers) such that $n = d q + r$ and $0 \le r \lt d$. We call $q$ the *quotient*, and $r$ the *remainder*. By the uniqueness, once you find *any* quotient-remainder pair that satisfies all the required conditions, you are done.

In the present case, take $n=c$, $d=a$, $q=1$ and $r=b$. Clearly $0 \leq r = b < a = d$, and 
$$
n = c = a+b = a \cdot 1 + b = d \cdot q + r.
$$ 
So from the above paragraph, we are done: $q=1$ is the quotient, and $r=b$ is the remainder obtained by dividing $n$ by $d$.

Comment: I am not really sure what theorem I am quoting exactly at the very beginning. Any help?

Comment: Maybe someone who was taught this English would be of better help, but it seems that the name _division theorem_ is ok: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_theorem), [google books](http://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&tbo=1&q=%22division+theorem%22+remainder&btnG=)

Comment: @Martin Sounds good, thanks. I was looking for remainder theorem, and found only the remainder theorem for polynomials.

Comment: @Srivatsan Narayanan: Oddly enough, a common name in English-language introductions to Number Theory is the *Division Algorithm*.

Answer (score 1):

This follows directly from the definition of congruence modulo an integer:

If $x,y,n\in \mathbb{Z}$, then $x\equiv y \mod(n)$ (which is semantically the same as $x \,\mod(n)\,=y$, although the former notation is more broadly used and, personally, I find the latter notation irritating) if $n \vert x-y$ (ie if there exists $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ with $nk=x-y$).

So, we know that $c=a+b$.  Use the definition above to s how that $c \equiv b \mod(a)$.  Note that it doesn't matter if $a>b$ or if either $a$ or $b$ are positive.  It's still the case that $a+b \equiv b\mod(a)$.

Comment: Well, as the mod/remainder operator, $x \pmod n$ is supposed to return an answer that is in the range $[0, n-1]$, I think. The $\equiv$ notation is broader. So in fact, we will need to prove the additional requirement that $0 \leq b < a$. Actually, there's nothing to *prove* in this case since we assumed this to be true, but we should at least note that this requirement is met by assumption.

Comment: It actually also matters which definition of $\equiv$ is used, unless the person asking is familiar with their equivalence. Does the mod n operator return the remainder when divided by $n$ or does it return the smallest possitive integer so that $n |a -r$?

Comment: @user9176 Neither.  Equivalence classes can have many representatives.

Comment: @SrivatsanNarayanan - I'm not familiar with that notation used for that specific meaning, but I suppose it could be useful.

Comment: @Jack, Actually you are right in that the original and more popular use of mod  and $\equiv$ is to denote congruence classes. But the use of $a \pmod b$ to denote the remainder obtained by dividing $a$ by $b$ is getting a bit more popular, I think, especially in more applied areas like algorithms.

Comment: Also, even if you work with congruence classes, one can introduce the equivalence relation mod n in two different (but equivalent ways): $a \equiv b \mod n$ means $n |b-a$ or $a \equiv b \mod n$ means a and b have the same reminder when divided by $n$. In math we ususally use the first definition, in computer science I think they use the second. I also saw the second used as a definition in some math classes. Of course WE know they are equivalent, but some of the students don't...